# getcwd for current location based on ftp account permission

Tags: php, ftp, getcwd

I'm trying to make a small script that's changing the permission for specific file using a ftp connection.
My problem is the absolute path. I have a ftp account wich land on the script directory (/script/). If i'm using getcwd, it will return the whole path (/home/user/public_html/script) but i need only the difference between the full path and the current path
(getcwd path: /home/user/public_html/script/
 ftp landing path: /script). So, how can i use getcwd to get the current directory for a ftp account? For example, if the user is landing in public_html, the path to the script will be /script/, or if he is landing inside /user, the path will be /public_html/script.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `getcwd` call will only work for your local system.  You need to program the logic to do the difference.

Comment: Any idea from where to start?

Answer (score 0):

In your script, you should do a:

```
var_dump($_ENV);
```

And check if there is a variable which will help you in conjunction with **getcwd()**. Then you can do some string work on both results to get the path you need.